# Search folder based on listbox to populate picturebox

Tags: vb.net, listbox, picturebox

I am trying to populate a picturebox with a listbox from a file.

I have the following code (which works fine). However, I would like to save some coding and search a folder for a file that matches the filename selected from the listbox. I have tried a few different things but am not nearly fluent enough with VB yet to make this work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    If ListBox1.SelectedItem = "test1" Then
        PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("c:Desktop\images\test1.jpg")


    Else 
    If ListBox1.SelectedItem = "test2" Then
        PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("c:Desktop\images\test2.jpg")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No Such File")
    End If
    Open_Button.Visible = True
    Open_Label.Visible = True
    Open_List.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it! Thank You Marc for your help.

```
 Dim file = System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\desktop\etc\", ListBox1.SelectedItem) + ".jpg"
    If ListBox1.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then

        If System.IO.File.Exists(file) Then

            PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(file)

        Else


            MessageBox.Show("No Image")
        End If
    End If
        Open_Button.Visible = True
        Open_Label.Visible = True
        Open_List.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not going to work in some cases. You should check ListBox1.SelectedItem for null BEFORE accessing it. This is the only difference to my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

If the name of the items matches with your file names, then you can handle everything with a single If/Else condition:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ListBox1.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim file = System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\YourPath\", ListBox1.SelectedItem) + ".jpg"
        If System.IO.File.Exist(file) Then
            PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(file)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No Such File")
        End If
        Open_Button.Visible = True
        Open_Label.Visible = True
        Open_List.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You for the response. I have been out of town and am just now able to test this... However, I am getting the following error:    https://www.dropbox.com/s/vvhz7lav1vf29iu/error.JPG?dl=0

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? It might be possible that `SelectedItem` is null. I have updated the code sample.

Comment: Still having the same problem on the same line.....file = Path.Combine("C:\YourPath\", ListBox1.SelectedItem) + ".jpg"

Comment: I have edited your code above..I added System.IO.  to Path.Combine and removed IF/Else....which works but now I will get an error if there is no image to match the file name.